# Stop Clippy showing mouse-over text

Tags: jquery, css, flash, actionscript

I've been play around with [Clippy](https://github.com/mojombo/clippy) and I having problems configuring it without compiling it myself.

I noticed on Github that they use use Clippy for repo urls but when you mouse over it it doesn't show the standard "Copy to clipboard" text. With the design I am working at at the moment I would really like to emulate this but can't seem to work out how they've done it. Looking at the Github source the swf they use also shows the text on mouse over so I assume they haven't customised the Clippy swf itself.

Does anyone who has used clippy before know what trick they might use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, the clippy.swf used by GitHub is of another version than the one you link to, a version that support more options, more flashvar parameters, where they state that no text should be used for the "copy to clipboard" and "copied!" messages, by setting these flashvars to empty (in the HTML code):

```
flashvars="id=url_box_clippy&copied=&copyto="
```

But i guess an alternative solution would be to set the width so that the text part of the swf is not displayed, setting the width to 14 (same as the width and height of the button, the clipboard icon). So width="14", and make sure scale="noscale" (and maybe salign="TL", for top left alignment).